# Why does scala reduce() and reduceLeft() reduce the sequence of the values in the same way?

Tags: scala, collections

If I run:

```
List(1, 4, 3, 9).reduce {(a, b) => println(s"$a + $b"); a + b}
```

The result is:

```
1 + 4
5 + 3
8 + 9
```

However, If I use `reduceLeft` instead of `reduce`, it also prints:

```
1 + 4
5 + 3
8 + 9
```

I have thought that `reduce` reduces the sequence of values in this way:

```
(1+4) + (3+9)
(5) + (12)
(17)
```

What is the real difference between `reduceLeft` and `reduce`?

Comment: _"I have thought that reduce reduces the sequence of values in this way:"_ ham no. Most implementation of `reduce ` just fallback to `reduceLeft` but they may fallback to `reduceRight` - `reduce` just doesn't guarantee in which order the operations are done, if you do not care about the order use `reduce` since the underlying collection will pick the most efficient order, if you need it from left to right or right to left pick one of the others; the difference is more about semantics than real implementation details. If you want something that is always in parallel search for `aggregate`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the type of the two functions:

```
def reduce[B >: A](op: (B, B) => B): B 
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B
```

Notice, how the second argument to `op` in `reduceLeft` is `A` (same as the element type), while in `reduce` it is `B` (same as the return value).

This is an important difference. The operation in reduce must be *associative*, meaning that you can split the list into several segments, apply operation to each of them separately, and then apply it again to the results to combine.

This is important when you want to do things in parallel: `reduce` can be applied in parallel to different parts of the list, and then the results can be combined.

`reduceLeft` on the other hand, can only work sequentially (left to right, as the name implies), operation does not have to be associative, and can expect its second parameter to always be an element of the sequence (and the first one – result of the operation so far);

Consider

```
    val sum = (1 to 100).reduce(_ + _)
```

This yields the same result as `(1 to 100).reduceLeft(_ + _)`, except that the former can be parallelized.
On the other hand:

```
    val strings = (1 to 100).reduceLeft[Any](_.toString + ";" + _.toString)
```

Should not be written as `reduce` (even though, in this contrived example, it can, and will even work as long as you stick with serial processing), because the result depends on the order in which elements are fed to the operation.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is:

1. `reduce` is *allowed* to reduce in any order; for a `List` it happens to be the same as `reduceLeft` because it's more efficient (and [it's the default implementation for `IterableOnceOps` subtypes](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/d23424cd3aa17f7ad95b81018c70ceed2566962b/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L692), so most of them will be the same). For another collection it could be equivalent to `reduceRight`, and for a tree type it may be more as you expected.
2. different type signatures:

   ```
   reduce[B >: A](op: (B, B) => B): B
   ```

   versus

   ```
   reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) => B): B
   ```

   because the first parameter to `op` in `reduceLeft` is always an element of the collection it's called on, but for `reduce` it could be the result of a recursive `reduce` call.